# What happens to Cron jobs if spring thread scheduler is full?

Tags: java, spring, cron, spring-integration, threadpool

in my application I have a spring thread scheduler pool which is used to run different Cron jobs at specific times in the future. 
I have the Cron jobs with sufficient logging to tell what it did.
I came to notice that sometimes these jobs didn't executed on the time it was supposed to run. I have verified that these jobs were added to the scheduler queue. So I suspect that if my scheduler pool is full and doesn't have any free threads then it failed to schedule the jobs on the specific time. Isn't spring supposed to run such delayed jobs when it finds any free threads in the pool? Or it just ignores this run and will run the job on the next schedule?

Answer (score 1):

That's not Spring responsibility. That's how a `ScheduledExecutorService` from Java works.

I believe that all those tasks are going to be executed whenever a thread from the pool is free. One by one according the queue.

Comment: Lets say I scheduled it to tun at 12 AM everyday. If at that time pool is exhausted, then will the cron job be tried next day at 12AM or if any thread becomes free?

Comment: No, they are executed whenever a thread is free in the pool. Please, study `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`